# Passing a variable to `renderMenuItemChildren` in react typeahead bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

From the `App` component it passes the variable`item` to the `Todo` component. From the `Todo` component passes to the`SearchResult` component. However, the `SearchResult 'component is not displayed.

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e2zqvd

```
import {Typeahead} from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: [{id:1, name: 'mario'}, {id:2, name: 'paul'}],
      item: 'flower'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Todo
          item = {this.state.item}
          name = {this.state.name}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Todo  extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
          <Typeahead
            id={'example4'}
            labelKey= 'name'
            multiple
            options={this.props.name}
            onChange={this.handleSelectPeopleToCalendar}
            ref={(ref) => this._typeahead = ref}
            renderMenuItemChildren={(option, props) => (
              <SearchResult
                key={option.id} 
                user={option} 
                item={props.item}
              />
            )}
          />
      </div>
    )
  } 
}

const SearchResult = ({user, item}) => (
    <div>
        <p>{item}</p>
        <span>{user.name}</span>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<SearchResult
            key={option.id} 
            user={option} 
            item={this.props.item}
          />
```

and you need start type something to see this component, there have input with no borders, and without background

[image]